# NDSolve a system of PDEs with Periodic Boundary Conditions

Tags: differential-equations, finite-element-method

I would like to analyse the system of differential equations

$\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
    \partial_tf_0&=\frac{C_{\mathbf{r}}}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\bigg)\partial_{\mathbf{r}}f_0\partial_{\mathbf{r}}f_0-\frac{\lambda}{2}\partial_{\mathbf{r}}f_0\partial_{\mathbf{r}}v_1\bigg]\\
    &+\frac{C_{\mathbf{r}}f_0}{(1+\lambda)^2}\partial^2_{\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}}\bigg[\bigg(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\bigg)f_0-\frac{\lambda}{2}v_1\bigg]+D\partial^2_{\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}}f_0\\\\
    \partial_tu_1&=\frac{C_{\mathbf{r}}}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\bigg)\partial_{\mathbf{r}}u_1\partial_{\mathbf{r}}f_0+\frac{C_{\mathbf{r}}u_1}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\bigg)\partial^2_{\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}}f_0\\
    &-D_{\phi}u_1+\omega v_1+D\partial^2 _{\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}}u_1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\Big(-\frac{D_{\phi}\varepsilon |f_1|^2u_1}{(\omega^2+4D_{\phi}^2)}-\frac{\omega\varepsilon |f_1|^2v_1}{(2\omega^2+8D_{\phi}^2)}+f_{0}u_1\Big)\\
    &-\frac{C_{\phi}}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg[\lambda u_1v_1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}v_1\varepsilon\frac{4D_{\phi}u_1v_1-\omega(u_1^2-v_1^2)}{8D_{\phi}^2+2\omega^2}\bigg]\\\\
    \partial_tv_1&=\frac{C_{\mathbf{r}}}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\bigg)\partial_{\mathbf{r}}v_1\partial_{\mathbf{r}}f_0+\frac{C_{\mathbf{r}}v_1}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg(1+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}\bigg)\partial^2_{\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}}f_0\\
    &-D_{\phi}v_1-\omega u_1+D\partial^2 _{\mathbf{r}\mathbf{r}}v_1+\frac{\varepsilon}{2}\Big(-\frac{D_{\phi}\varepsilon |f_1|^2v_1}{(\omega^2+4D_{\phi}^2)}+\frac{\omega\varepsilon |f_1|^2u_1}{(2\omega^2+8D_{\phi}^2)}+f_{0}v_1\Big)\\
    &+\frac{C_{\phi}}{(1+\lambda)^2}\bigg[\lambda u_1^2+\frac{\lambda^2}{2}u_1\varepsilon\frac{ 4D_{\phi}u_1v_1-\omega(u_1^2-v_1^2)}{(2\omega^2+8D_{\phi}^2)}\bigg]
\end{split}
\end{equation}$

defined on $\mathbb{T}^2$, with $\mathbf{r}=(x,y)\in[0,L]\times[0,L]$, i.e. periodic boundary conditions on both x and y directions. I was trying MMA's NDSolve using PeriodicBoundaryConditions with my code below.Then it returns an error:

[image: error message]

Could anyone tell what it meant actually? Thanks

```
    eqf = D[f0[x, y, t], t] == 
   C2/(1 + lam)^2*((1 + lam^2/2) (D[f0[x, y, t], x]^2 + 
          D[f0[x, y, t], y]^2) - 
       2*lam*(D[f0[x, y, t], x]*D[v[x, y, t], x] + 
          D[f0[x, y, t], y]*D[v[x, y, t], y])) + 
    C2*(f0[x, y, t] + 
        rho)/(1 + 
         lam)^2*((1 + lam^2/2) (D[f0[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + 
          D[f0[x, y, t], {y, 2}]) - 
       2*lam*(D[v[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[v[x, y, t], {y, 2}])) + 
    D1*(D[f0[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[f0[x, y, t], {y, 2}]);

    equ = D[u[x, y, t], t] == 
   C2/(1 + lam)^2*(1 + lam^2/2) (D[u[x, y, t], x]*D[f0[x, y, t], x] + 
       D[u[x, y, t], y]*D[f0[x, y, t], y]) + 
    C2*u[x, y, 
       t]/(1 + lam)^2*((1 + lam^2/2) (D[f0[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + 
         D[f0[x, y, t], {y, 2}])) + 
    D1*(D[u[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[u[x, y, t], {y, 2}]) - 
    D2*u[x, y, t] + om*v[x, y, t] + 
    ep/2*(-D2*ep*(u[x, y, t]^2 + v[x, y, t]^2)*
        u[x, y, t]/(om^2 + 4*D2^2) - 
       om*ep*(u[x, y, t]^2 + v[x, y, t]^2)*
        v[x, y, t]/(2*om^2 + 8*D2^2) + (f0[x, y, t] + rho)*
        u[x, y, t]) - 
    C2/(1 + lam)^2*(lam*u[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t] + 
       lam^2/2*ep*
        v[x, y, t]*(4*D2*u[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t] - 
           om*(u[x, y, t]^2 - v[x, y, t]^2))/(2*om^2 + 8*D2^2));

    eqv = D[v[x, y, t], t] == 
   C2/(1 + lam)^2*(1 + lam^2/2) (D[v[x, y, t], x]*D[f0[x, y, t], x] + 
       D[v[x, y, t], y]*D[f0[x, y, t], y]) + 
    C2*v[x, y, 
       t]/(1 + lam)^2*((1 + lam^2/2) (D[f0[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + 
         D[f0[x, y, t], {y, 2}])) + 
    D1*(D[v[x, y, t], {x, 2}] + D[v[x, y, t], {y, 2}]) - 
    D2*v[x, y, t] - om*u[x, y, t] + 
    ep/2*(-D2*ep*(u[x, y, t]^2 + v[x, y, t]^2)*
        v[x, y, t]/(om^2 + 4*D2^2) + 
       om*ep*(u[x, y, t]^2 + v[x, y, t]^2)*
        u[x, y, t]/(2*om^2 + 8*D2^2) + (f0[x, y, t] + rho)*
        v[x, y, t]) + 
    C2/(1 + lam)^2*(lam*u[x, y, t]*u[x, y, t] + 
       lam^2/2*ep*
        u[x, y, t]*(4*D2*u[x, y, t]*v[x, y, t] - 
           om*(u[x, y, t]^2 - v[x, y, t]^2))/(2*om^2 + 8*D2^2));

    eqs = {eqf, equ, eqv};
pbcx = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[{f0[x, y, t], u[x, y, t], 
   v[x, y, t]}, x == 0, TranslationTransform[{L, 0, 0}]]

pbcy = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[{f0[x, y, t], u[x, y, t], 
   v[x, y, t]}, y == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, L, 0}]]
    pbcs = {pbcx, pbcy};
    rho = 1.5;
    ep = 10;
    lam = 5 e - 2;
    D1 = 1;
    D2 = 1;
    om = 10;
    C2n = 12;
    C2 = rho^C2n;
    L = 100;

    pbcx = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[{f0[x, y, t], u[x, y, t], v[x, y, t]}, x == 0, TranslationTransform[{L, 0, 0}]];
    pbcy = PeriodicBoundaryCondition[{f0[x, y, t], u[x, y, t], v[x, y, t]}, y == 0, TranslationTransform[{0, L, 0}]];
    pbcs = {pbcx, pbcy};
    NDSolveValue[eqs, pbcs, f0, u, v, {x, 0, L}, {y, 0, L}, {t, 0, 100}, Method ->{"MethodOfLines", "SpatialDiscretization" -> {"FiniteElement"}}];
```

Comment: _Equation or list of equations expected instead of eqs in the first argument eqs._ please fix.

Comment: You write `NDSolveValue[eqs` but there is no `eqs` anywhere!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [tour] now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please provide `eqs` so that readers can help you with this problem.  Also,, your use of `NDSolveValue` contains syntax errors.  Check the documentation and correct them in your question.

Comment: You need to write `{eqs, pbcs}` instead of eqs, pbcs from what I understand, but more clarity in your question is needed for a clear answer

Comment: @FilipeMiguel Thanks. More details already added

Comment: @YiweiZhang try repacing eqs, pbcs by Flatten[{eqs, pbqs}]

Comment: @FilipeMiguel Thanks, then it returns:NDSolveValue::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of f0[x,y,t] in the first argument {f0[x,y,t],u[x,y,t],v[x,y,t]}.